# En que me estoy equivocando al hacer push?

Tags: github, push

soy principiante y tengo los siguientes comandos para hacer push en el cmd, en github, pero por alguna razon no logro hacerlo:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Titulo del proyecto"
git push
```

Comment: te aparece algún mensaje de error¿?

Comment: debes de colocar la rama a la que deseas enviar los cambios.. generalmente seria..."git push origin master"...

Comment: mas detalles: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html...

Comment: Si es la primera vez que haces push, puede que necesites setear el upstream `git push --set-upstream   origin master `

Comment: Gracias Diego y Joel, en efecto es la primera vez que lo hago y me faltaba setear el upstream, gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, como se dejan votos a las respuestas? Lo siento, apenas voy aprendiendo de esto.

Comment: @JoelIbaceta nótese que tu comentario sirvió para resolver el tema, recomiendo que lo conviertas en respuesta para que se vea mejor y el autor de la pregunta pueda aceptarla

Comment: @ErikAlatriste vuelve a mirar el [tour]. Ahi se explica el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te has cambiado de rama ni creado una nueva y el repo es un clone de un repo remoto. Debes indicar el remoto y el nombre de la rama que deseas subir. Por ejemplo:

```
git push origin master
```

Siendo **origin** el **repo remoto** y **master** el nombre de la rama local que deseas subir. 
Puede que no tengas la direccion del repo remoto. Para ello puedes añadir remotos con el siguiente comando:

```
git remote add <NombreDelRemoto> <URLdelRepoRemoto>
```

Puedes consultar todos los repos remotos que tienes en el repo local con:

```
git remote
```

Tambien debo añadir que a la hora de realizar el commit, con las opciones `-m "Titulo del proyecto"` estas indicando el texto que deseas añadir al commit, por lo general y por conveniencia, debería de ser un breve resumen que describa los cambios que has hecho en el commit.

Comment: Muchas gracias David, tu comentario tambien me ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @ErikAlatriste si esta respuesta respondio tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Listo, ya esta marcada!